# Hide elements of an Angular directive for certain situations

Tags: html, angular, directive

Being a directive called `my-directive`. The template of the directive contains 2 elements:

```
<div>
    <!-- element1 -->
</div>
<div>
    <!-- element2 -->
</div>
```

Adding it into another html file is done by:

```
<app-my-directive></app-my-directive>
```

My question is, is there a way to make this directive show only `element1` if it is added into a certain html but show all its element otherwise?

Comment: I'd assume you can do an `ngIf` in the directive, and then set the value for the conditional *outside* of the directive's reference ... but can't confirm this.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular 2+?

Comment: @yazantahhan Angular2+, Angular 8 more specific

Answer (score 2):

You can send an input to detect which element to show:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-directive',
  inputs: ['myCondition'],
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="myCondition">
        <!-- element1 -->
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!myCondition">
        <!-- element2 -->
    </div>
  `
})
class MyDirective {
    myCondition: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-directive',
      template: `
        <div *ngIf="myCondition">
            <!-- element1 -->
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!myCondition">
            <!-- element2 -->
        </div>
      `
    })
    class MyDirective {
        @Input() myCondition: boolean;
    }
```